# How do i write visualTransformation code in jetpack compose project?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I need to apply some rules to textfield while user enters the text. So i found the `AnnotatedStringBuilded` called `VisualTranformation` in jetpack compose. I tried writing the code to fullfill the required rules for textfields but its not working.

Here is the code that i have tried :

```
class FormattedTextFieldString(val text: String) : VisualTransformation {
    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
        val filteredText = buildAnnotatedString {
            text.forEachIndexed { index, char ->
                if (char.isDigit() || (char == '.' && indexOf('.') == -1)) {
                    append(char)
                }
            }
        }

        if (filteredText.text.contains('.')) {
            val dotIndex = filteredText.text.indexOf('.')
            val digitsAfterDot = filteredText.text.length - dotIndex - 1
            if (digitsAfterDot > 2) {
                removeRange(dotIndex + 2, filteredText.length)
            }
        }

        return TransformedText(filteredText)
    }
}
```

I want these rules :

- Users are restricted from inputting any special characters except for the dot (.)
- Users are limited to inputting the dot only once.
- Following the dot, only two digits are permitted.
- The input field does not accept spaces.
- Users are prohibited from pasting or typing anything other than numerical digits.